# Video missing when concatenating two videos with blank section in between using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to concatenate two videos with a blank section of video in between. The screenshots are captured from an Android device and I need to reconstitute them into a continuous run, however gaps appear in the middle because the video can only be three minutes when captured from the android device screen.

Here's how I am doing it:

I have created a PNG with size 1200x1920.

Then used it to create a small video on the command line:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i screen-black.png -vcodec h264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p  screen-black.mp4
```

I have created this text file to pass to ffmpeg:

```
file 'vid1.mp4'
file 'screen-black.mp4'
file 'vid2.mp4'
```

And finally executed:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy concat_output.mp4
```

When I watch the newly created video, the first and second videos from the android device are put together, however the blank video in the middle is missing.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

I thought it might be something to do with the codec, however all videos are in H264. One noticeable thing is the blank video has a resolution of 3072 × 1920, whereas the other two videos have a resolution of 1200 x 1920

(Just in case it is relevant, I'm doing this on a Mac so the file has to be compatible with Quicktime).

Comment: Show the output of `ffmpeg -i` for all three files.

Comment: vid1.mp4:
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vid1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2017-10-06T02:00:23.000000Z
    com.android.version: 6.0.1
  Duration: 00:03:08.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 13 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1200x1920, 12 kb/s, 0.51 fps, 3.25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-10-06T02:00:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
At least one output file must be specified

Comment: vid2.mp4:
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vid2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2017-10-06T02:29:20.000000Z
    com.android.version: 6.0.1
  Duration: 00:02:55.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 23 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1200x1920, 23 kb/s, 2.55 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-10-06T02:29:20.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
At least one output file must be specified

Comment: out.mp4:
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'screen-black.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:15.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1200x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:8], 16 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
At least one output file must be specified

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i screen-black.png -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -video_track_timescale 90k -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p  screen-black.mp4`.

Comment: That is working in so far as the blank video is being inserted, however it is being distorted. Comes out as a gray blur (instead of the black original). Also, if I concat with just the screen-black mp4 infront of the vid2 mp4, the start is black, but the second video is distorted.

Comment: Instead of putting this in the comments, please [edit] your post and add the info there. Please show the complete output of the last command you ran, too.

Comment: At this stage, quickest way forward is to re-encode, so, in concat cmd, drop the `-c copy`.